# what is the relationship between contract accounts and smart contracts?

Tags: contract-deployment, smart-contract-wallets

I am confused; some textbooks refer to account contracts as smart contracts while others have different sections. Are these two concepts the same!

To the best of my knowledge, contract accounts are one type of Ethereum accounts that can not initiate a transaction. However, it has many specifications of a contract account, such as a code field.

Typically, I thought that a code field is where your bytecode lives based on the complied solidity program, the smart contract. Hence, I thought a smart contract is under the umbrella of an account contract. Am I right in my thought? Would you please correct me if I am mistaken, as I am still learning the concepts?

Answer (score 0):

Etherum account is defined as:

```
// Account is the Ethereum consensus representation of accounts.
// These objects are stored in the main account trie.
type Account struct {
    Nonce    uint64
    Balance  *big.Int
    Root     common.Hash // merkle root of the storage trie
    CodeHash []byte
}
```

If it has `CodeHash` then it is a contract, if it doesn't then it is an EOA (Externally Owned Account.

That's it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate further. So you are saying that EOA or contract account has similar specifications the only difference is the CodeHash? So, isn't that deviating from my main question? Like is a smart contract a code that is complied and inserted in one of the fields of a contract account?

Comment: That's pretty much it. The contract account is just an ethereum address that holds a smart contract (= that has a codeHash != 0, as opposed to an EOA) and the "smart contract" is just the code in itself. At least thats how i see it.

Comment: I thought that each contract account has a different code in it to run different computations. codeHash represents a code of an account on the Ethereum virtual machine (EVM) that may contain complied solidity programming? Then why do developers call smart contract same as account contracts? What is the need for the address of the account contract then?

Comment: the code of the contract is stored in the LevelDB database using `put()` function, and retrieved using `get()` function as it is commonly used in NoSQL databases (check out key-value pair storage)

Comment: @rsc05 so how do you transfer money to contract account if it is not by its address?

Comment: @rsc05 the address purpose is identifying the contract. To make a call to a specific contract you need a way to differentiate it from the others dont you? Even if it has the exact same bytecode, which isnt uncommon.

Comment: @Foxxxey Can two different contract addresses have the same bytecode? How could that be and if that happens what does this mean?

Comment: Yes that can happen, if you deploy the same contract 2 times you'll end up with 2 different contract addresses which have the same bytecode. Uniswap pairs are a good exemple of that